# Different JVM behavior: start tomcat from Eclipse vs start from Catalina.bat

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm

I am maintaining a web application that uses java.protocol.handler. I initialize it with a value using: `-Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=<my value>`. 
The problem is following: 
1. If I deploy the app. to tomcat from eclipse directly, using this [instruction](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-run-a-maven-web-application-in-tomcat-from-eclipse.html?page=2) (directly referring to Tomcat main class) and pass the  `-Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=<my value>` argument in VM arguments tab, the app works properly and -protocol dependent bean is initialized.

2.If I deploy the .war file directly to Tomcat/webapps and start tomcat with `catalina.bat` (adding  `-Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=<my value>` to `JAVA_OPTS`) I get: `Malformed URL supplied Exception`.
3.If I start Tomcat from eclipse (and specify VM arguments similar to point 1.) the same .war will be deployed correctly.

My guess is there is difference between how catalina.bat and eclipse initialize VM parameters. Or maybe I should attach my projects .jars to Tomcat somehow.

Thank you for any hints. I can provide more details of required

Comment: Your details are slightly sketchy - you should probably provide the -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=XXX value, or even the entire .bat file that causes the error. Also full details of the error including a stack trace if possible.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot provide the exact protocol name, but I assumed its not really relevant since it works in some cases, thats why I head toward JVM setup differences. As for catalina.bat - it is standard, unchanged file from Apache Tomcat 6.0.35, setenv.bat file:
set JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=<custom protocol> -DJINTEGRA_NATIVE_MODE

Comment: Error (unfortunately cant copy the stack trace since I use some propertiary java classes): 
Property "configURL" threw exception; nested exception: Malformed URL supplied: null.
My guess is this error occurs becasue JVM java.protocol.handler.pkgs argument was somehow not initialized, or was initialized AFTER the bean that depends on it was created, hence URL is treated as malformed

Comment: sry for double post, cant edit:
Unfortunately I cannot provide the exact protocol name, but I assumed its not really relevant since it works in some cases, thats why I head toward JVM setup differences. As for catalina.bat - it is standard, unchanged file from Apache Tomcat 6.0.35, setenv.bat file:
set JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=<custom protocol> -DJINTEGRA_NATIVE_MODE
I will also mention that I use maven dependencies to download java.protocl.handler .jar and Spring to initialize Bean with the URL. Where URL is in <custom_protocol> format.

Comment: Without more specific information (that you are unable to provide) you are unlikely to get anything beyond speculation.

Comment: Yes, I was afraid that might happen. I was hoping that there is some tomcat vm configuration or a way in which tomcat provides its VM parameters to deployed projects that I am missing.

Comment: You could try -verbose:class to see the sequence of class loading? Other than that, you'd have to come up with a 'test' custom protocol and post all the info on here, so people can try it for you and debug it for you.

Comment: ok, will try to work on something like that and let you know

Comment: I have found this article, which might also shed some light to the issue, meanwhile working on testable program
http://www.unicon.net/node/776
Is this fragment meaningful in terms of tomcat deployment:
    "Handler implementations must be visible to the System class loader, and therefore they must be packaged separately from your application and grafted to your container "after market"
    The 'java.protocol.handler.pkgs' system property is only read one time, as the JVM starts up, so (in most cases) you have to dig into and modify the scripts that launch your container" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments, it's hard to know what's going on without more information, but maybe this will help.  Tomcat calls `URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory` to set its own `URLStreamHandlerFactory`, which overrides the default behaviour of the `java.protocol.handler.pkgs` system property.  You can't then call `URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory` with your own handler without breaking internal Tomcat functionality.  The system of URLStreamHandlers certainly isn't Java's greatest feature.

The only way I've found to reliably use my own stream handler is to pass it into the [URL constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#URL%28java.net.URL,%20java.lang.String,%20java.net.URLStreamHandler%29):

```
URL url = new URL( null, "http://example.com", myURLStreamHandler );
```

Comment: Hi, getting back with the issue; to sum up:
Nathan's solutions did the trick. I was lucky enough to be able to request source code for the affected class (since it had its properties set with String values and I had to change that).
So indeed: tomcat, if started from catalina.bat overrides users java.protocol... settings. the same happened to me when I tried using Jetty, as mentioned in another thread.
So generally there are problems with java.protocol.handler.pkgs when using tomcat and jetty. Luckly I had acces to source code.

Answer (score 0):

We've noticed that -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs="my.protocol" works in Tomcat 6.0.x IF the protocol implementation is in the Tomcat lib folder and not in a war...

Maybe this helps others

Comment: I can explain this: Once the URL.handlers map is added a concrete protocol handler, it is not re-evaluated again. If handler class appears in WebApp class path – it is already too late (unless one tries to override handler for exotic protocol which was not requested so far, e.g. `gopher://`). Thus the class should be loadable by system class loader.